# SAS import word by word

Tags: import, sas, cpu-word

I have one (maybe silly) question. I have a text(it cames from an xml which is longer) file which looks like:

```
<Hi>
|<interview><rul| |ebook><name>EQU| |OTE_RULES</name| |><version>aaaa| |ON 
QUOTE TR2 v2| |.14</version></| |rulebook><creat| |edDate>2017-10-| 
|23`16:00:16.581| | UTC</createdDa| |te><status>IN_P| |ROGRESS</$10tus| 
|>`<lives>`<life n| |umber="1" clien| |tId="1" status=| |"IN_PROGRESS"><| 
|pages>`<page cod| | e="QD_APP" numb| |er="1" name="Pl| |an type" create| 
|dDate="2017-10-| </Hi>
```

I would like to know if there is any way to import word by word, so I could clean the text an remove characters such as $ or to keep the space such as

```
|umber="1" clien| 
| e="QD_APP" numb|
```

Thank fyou for your help

Julen

Comment: Could you use text to columns in Excel to split at the `|` and then do your modifications there?

Comment: I can't, I would like to have everything with code(not manullay) and I would like all my code in SAS (if not i would need to use a batch file and I think that It would be more complicate)

Answer (score 0):

SAS can certainly input by word as opposed to by ... whatever else you're inputting by. In fact the most simple way to import would be:

```
data want;
  infile "yourfile.xml";
  length word $1024; *or whatever the longest feasible "word" would be;
  input word $ @@;
run;
```

If you don't tell SAS how to split words, it assumes spaces, for example.